# R - How to get the time elapsed between two points?

Tags: r, time

I've tried to use `Sys.time` to get the time elapsed between two points. However, it doesn't output in a way I like.

This is how it looks now:

```
a <- Sys.time
...running stuff between these two points...
b <- Sys.time
c <- b - a
c
Time difference of 1.00558 hours
```

I only want the number and the units. I know that to get just the number I can do:

```
c[[1]]
```

However, sometimes the result of `c` can give me seconds or minutes. I only want instances wherein I have the number and when the units are in hours. Does anyone know of a way such that I would get something like the following, using Sys.time() (or any alternative):

```
if (units == "hours")
{
  if (number => 1)
  {
      #do something
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe `difftime(b, a, units="hours")` or something

Comment: As an aside, you really shouldn't use `c` as a variable name because it is an important function.

Comment: As @Frank said, you can specify the units of a difftime object. You can also compare it to a number, so if your difftime object is in hours, you can do mydiff>=2 and it will return True if it is more than 2 hours.

Answer (score 7):

Using `difftime` of base R allows you to obtain the time difference in different units. Rest is formatting.

```
a = Sys.time()
Sys.sleep(5)    #do something
b = Sys.time()    
paste0(round(as.numeric(difftime(time1 = b, time2 = a, units = "secs")), 3), " Seconds")
#[1] "5.091 Seconds"
```

Answer (score 2):

The package `tictoc` simplifies this kind of timing. It doesn't return hours, but we can create a new function that converts its second-based measurements into hours.

```
library(tictoc)

toc_hour <- function() {
  x <- toc()
  (x$toc - x$tic) / 3600
}
```

You normally start the timer with `tic()` and stop it with `toc()`.

```
tic()
Sys.sleep(2)
toc()
# 2.02 sec elapsed
```

Calling `toc_hour()` instead of `toc()` returns the number of hours that have elapsed.

```
tic()
Sys.sleep(2)
toc_hour()
# 2.25 sec elapsed
#  elapsed 
# 0.000625
```

It still prints the number of seconds above the hours, but if you capture the result it will only store the number of hours for downstream analysis.

```
tic()
Sys.sleep(2)
x <- toc_hour()

if(x < 1) {print("This took under an hour")}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try the [´tictoc´](https://cran.r-project.org/package=tictoc) package.
As described in the documentation you can do the following:

```
tic()

#Do something

toc(log = TRUE, quiet = TRUE)

#Put the result in a log
log.txt <- tic.log(format = TRUE)

#Extract only the value
res <- gsub( " sec elapsed", "", unlist(log.txt))

#Clear the log
tic.clearlog()
```

That way, `res` gives you only the value and is in seconds, so it is pretty simple to have hours then.
Moreover, if you don't clear the log you can put successions of `tic()` and `toc()` and put everything in your `log.txt`, and then `gsub( " sec elapsed", "", unlist(log.txt))` will give you a vector of strings with the value in seconds for each iteration which can be pretty useful

Answer (score 1):

I think lubridate is the quickest solution for you:

```
start <- Sys.time()
## Do Stuff here
end <- Sys.time()
elapsed <- lubridate::ymd_hms(end) - lubridate::ymd_hms(start) 
message(elapsed)
```

It should return something useful like:
"Time difference of 12.1 hours"

Comment: `start` and `end` are already `POSIXct`. There is no need for `lubridate::ymd_hms` in your solution

Answer (score 1):

You can evaluate everything as an argument to the `system.time` function. It will give you the elapsed time in seconds.

```
paste0(system.time( rnorm(1000000, 0, 1) )[3] / 3600, " hours")
# "2.58333333334172e-05 hours"
```

Alternatively, you can use Frank's suggestion in the comments.  `difftime(b, a, units = "hours")` which is probably the dominant solution in most cases

Answer (score 1):

The tictoc package normally returns seconds. The other solutions from this package  manually converts this to other units but I find it still doesn't look right. Instead, use the built-in func.toc argument in toc() to change the output. For example:

```
toc_min <- function(tic,toc,msg="") {
  mins <- round((((toc-tic)/60)),2)
  outmsg <- paste0(mins, " minutes elapsed")
}
```

And then:

```
tic()
Sys.sleep(1)
toc(func.toc=toc_min)
```

returns

```
0.02 minutes elapsed
```